# Wordgame in Python

Tags: python, game

I'd like feedback please as to improvements which could be made to make this more 'pythonic' in its approach/structure.  Any constructive feedback welcome.  The below is a game which takes a single random word from a list of 3000 and has the player guess letters (whilst being limited to a certain number of attempts).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import random
import linecache
import sys

sourcefile = 'wordlist'  # list of words


def playagain():
    response = input('Do you want to play again? ')
    response = response.lower()
    if response == 'yes' or response == 'y':
        main()
    else:
        print('OK...')
        sys.exit(0)


def find_word():
    random_line = random.randint(1, 3000)  # random line number
    chosen_word = linecache.getline(sourcefile, random_line)
    str_chosen_word = chosen_word.strip('\n')
    return str_chosen_word.lower()


def getIndexPositions(list_chosen_word, char):
    indexPosList = []
    indexPos = 0
    while True:
        try:
            # Search for item in list from indexPos to the end of list
            indexPos = list_chosen_word.index(char, indexPos)
            # Add the index position in list
            indexPosList.append(indexPos)
            indexPos += 1
        except ValueError as e:
            break

    return indexPosList


def main():
    guessed = []  # create list to track guessed letters
    list_masked_word = []  # create list to show progress of guessing
    str_chosen_word = find_word()  # get random word
    list_chosen_word = list(str_chosen_word)  # create list from word
    length_list_chosen_word = len(list_chosen_word)  # length of word
    attempts = length_list_chosen_word + 3  # number of attempts
    list_masked_word = ['\u25A0'] * length_list_chosen_word  # masking
    game(attempts, guessed, list_chosen_word, list_masked_word)


def game(attempts, guessed, list_chosen_word, list_masked_word):
    print()
    print('Welcome to the word game')
    while (attempts != 0):
        print()
        print('You have', attempts, 'attempts to guess the word correctly')
        print('So far you have found: ', ''.join(list_masked_word))
        attempts -= 1  # reduce the number of attempts available
        guess = str(input('Enter a letter: ')).lower()
        if len(guess) == 1:
            if guess in guessed:
                print('Ooops - You have already tried that letter')
            else:
                guessed.append(guess)  # keeps track of letters guessed
                indexPosList = getIndexPositions(list_chosen_word, guess)
                for index in indexPosList:
                    list_masked_word[index] = guess
                if list_chosen_word == list_masked_word:
                    print('The word was: ',''.join(list_chosen_word))
                    print('Well Done - you guessed the word')
                    playagain()

        else:
            print()
            print('Enter only one letter!')
    print()
    print('You are out of guesses')
    playagain()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What is this program? What is it supposed to do and why does it exist? Please add context; thanks.

Comment: It's a word game. It takes a random word. Masks it. The player has a certain number of attempts to guess the correct word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Global constants

```
sourcefile = 'wordlist'  # list of words
```

should be

```
SOURCE_FILE = 'wordlist'  # list of words
```

### Looping instead of recursion

```
if response == 'yes' or response == 'y':
    main()
```

For a small number of replays this will have no noticeable ill effect, but if an obsessive user replays enough, they will eventually blow the stack. Replace this with a loop at the upper level in `main`.

### Function names

```
def getIndexPositions
```

should be

```
def get_index_positions
```

and similar snake_case for your local variables.

### State passing

Why are `guessed` and `list_masked_word` passed into `game`? They seem like they should just be initialized within `game` without being parameters.

### String interpolation

```
'You have', attempts, 'attempts to guess the word correctly'
```

is more easily expressed as

```
f'You have {attempts} attempts to guess the word correctly'
```

### Loop syntax

This:

```
while (attempts != 0):
```

does not need parens. Also, rather than manually decrementing it, you can do

```
for attempt in range(attempts, 0, -1):
```

### Typo

`Ooops` -> `Oops`

### Early-continue

I find that this:

```
    if len(guess) == 1:
        # lots of code...
    else:
        print()
        print('Enter only one letter!')
```

is more easily legible as

```
    if len(guess) != 1:
        print()
        print('Enter only one letter!')
        continue

    # lots of code...
```